# TabbedPage on MonoAndroid

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Community and a physical device (Android 7.0 smartphone).

I am looking for ways to launch a TabbedPage from MainActivity.cs.  The project is not Cross Platform, just C# Android app on VS.

Please help.  Thanks

Comment: Please add what you have tried (and failed) so that someone can help with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `TabbedPage` control of XF in Xamarin Android project, then you may need to know, in XF, `TabbedPage` is rendered use Android native control `TabLayout` through [TabbedPageRenderer](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/AppCompat/TabbedPageRenderer.cs). So, you can directly use `TabLayout` in Xamarin.Android.

To use `TabLayout` in Xamarin.Android, you will need to install [Xamarin.Android.Support.Design](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Design/) package.

You may check this blog: [TabLayout](https://blog.falafel.com/31-days-of-xamarin-android-day-23-tablayout/) to know how to implement a `TabLayout` in Xamarin.Android project.

Comment: Thanks Grace, so you are sure I can't launch TabbedPage from code in the MainActivity?

Comment: Thank you Grace.  Why does VS allow me to add a TabbedPage and ContentPage when I choose Add > New Item >?